# How to manage hash change event in a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#?_page=map" class="map-it right">Map It </a>
```

Also a click event in jquery:

```
jQuery('a.map-it').click(function(){
    jQuery('#map-wrapper').addClass('map-tog');
    jQuery('section, dl, div.dtl-block-2').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery(window).hashchange(function() {
        jQuery('#map-wrapper').removeClass('map-tog');
        jQuery('section, dl, div.dtl-block-2').removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

My requirement is when I click on 'Map it' showing a map and also hiding some content part. To click a browser back button then map will hide and show content. But above code is not working properly. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: try taking the hashchange event out of the click handler

Comment: There is no `hashchange` jQuery method that I know of. Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: ahh yes, use `on()` for that. You should have seen errors thrown for `function is undefined` or similar such description

Comment: are you using any plugin like [this](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/) to support `hashchange`

Answer (score 0):

Try window.onhashchange event

```
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
                //Do something
            }
```

Comment: The two functions are working fine. The problem is, when I click 'Map it' button both the function will execute. So the map will appear and hide.

Comment: Bind the event listener for hash as shown above outside the click event, then it will work as expected!

Comment: Is this has any alternate solution?

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the following code, if it helps in any way...

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onhashchange = function(e) 
{
  alert("My current hash is " + window.location.hash);
}

$(function()
{
$('a.map-it').click(function()
{
    alert("Hoorray i was clicked");
});
})
</script>

<a class="map-it" href="#?_page=map">Click me to check hash</a>
```